# Coder workspace creation failing

Tags: docker, vscode-remote, code-server, coder

I am trying to set up [Coder](https://coder.com/) via Docker with docker-compose.

I defined it as a service in my docker-compose.yml ([based on this in-line command](https://coder.com/docs/v2/latest/install/docker#run-coder-with-the-built-in-database-quick)):

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  coder:
    image: codercom/coder:1.35.0
    ports:
      - "7080:7080"
    group_add:
      - 134 # added docker group for write permissions
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /srv/databases/docker/data/volumes/coder:/var/run/coder
```

The UI is then accessible and I can login with the provided credentials, but when I try to create a workspace, the process fails in step *11: create workspace: Failed to create Container-based Virtual Machine: start boots*

```
create workspace: Failed to create Container-based Virtual Machine: start bootstrap: execute bootstrap failed: docker exec: exec cmd "/usr/bin/docker exec -i -u 1000 coder /bin/sh -s": exit status 28
```

For the workspace I defined the image "codercom/enterprise-jupyter", listed under the pre-defined "Packaged" section.

The workspace provider by default is Docker.

**What is going wrong and how can I fix it?**

How it looks in the UI:

[image]

**Update:**

I found out, that a container is being created for the environment:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                  PORTS                                                                                                                                                            NAMES
f06eb1365588   coderenvs/envbox:1.35.0-rc.2    "/envbox legacy"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                                                                                                                                                        goofy_noether
db2666b7bdf9   codercom/coder:1.35.0           "/coderd run --bind …"   2 minutes ago        Up About a minute       5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7080->7080/tcp, :::7080->7080/tcp                                                                                                              infrastructure-management_coder_1
```

Inspecting the log via `docker logs f06eb1365588` shows an error message:

```
{"ts":"2023-02-23T09:56:09.937651147Z","level":"ERROR","msg":"child log","logger_name":"sysbox-fs","fields":{"process":"sysbox-fs","content":"time=\"2023-02-23 09:56:09\" level=error msg=\"Failed to write to /proc/sys/net/core/default_qdisc: open /proc/sys/net/core/default_qdisc: no such file or directory\""}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not exactly solve this issue, but I was able to create workspaces with coder/coder version 2, not version 1.

I used docker-compose for that as references by the documentation: https://github.com/coder/coder/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml